# Is there a standard JDK interface which a method like void run() throws Exception?

Tags: java

What I want is a standard JDK class that look like this:

```
interface ExplodingRunnable {
    void run() throws Exception;
}
```

[Callable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) is no good, because its [call()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html#call%28%29) method is required to return a value, but I need a `void`.

[Runnable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) is no good, because its [run()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html#run%28%29) method doesn't declare `throws Exception`.

I sort of need a combination of the two. Any ideas?

**EDIT:** I should have mentioned that I tried `Callable<Void>` but it requires you to define a method:

```
public Void call() {
    // run your code;
    return null; // ugly!
}
```

I'm looking for something a bit nicer.

Why do I want this?

I'm implementing a standard why of catching "will never happen" Exceptions (they will never happen, but various APIs define their methods throwing Exceptions) and throwing any Exceptions that *might* occur by wrapping them in an (unchecked) RuntimeException, so the caller can simply pass a "ExplodingRunnable" in and not have to code loads of perfunctory try/catch blocks that will never be exercised.

**FINAL EDIT** It looks like what I was looking for doesn't exist. The accepted answer is the closest to "correct", but it looks like there is no solution to answer the question as asked.

Comment: Why do you need to throw an exception in a `run()` method? Couldn't you just use a try/catch block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An interface with only one method, which returns `void` and throws `Exception`.

Among all `java` and `javax` classes, only one fits that description:

```
package java.lang;

public interface AutoCloseable
{
    void close() throws Exception;
}
```

Well... the word "close" has many meanings...

---

You want to surround a bunch of statements with some extra handling, there is no sin to define your own interface here. You may find that your API requires users to learn 4 new phrases

```
Util.muckException( new ExplodingRunnable() { public void run() throws Exception
 ^1     ^2                  ^3                             ^4
```

You can actually cut down two, and user code would look like this

```
new MuckException(){ public void run() throws Exception
{
    statement_1;
    ...
    statement_n;
}};

public abstract class MuckException
{
    public abstract run() throws Exception;

    public MuckException()
    {
        try{ run(); }
        catch(Exception e){ throw new Error(e); }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is *exactly* what I am trying to do. I want to put the handling of all these "never/rarely happen" Exceptions in one place and lose all the try/catching in the calling code. If nothing else comes up I'll accept this answer, but "close()"??? It's an unfortunate name for a "do it" method

Comment: Your answer is excellent. I particularly like your MuckException pattern, especially the in-constructor auto call!

Comment: If we have closure, we can cut ^3 and ^4, leaving a shorter syntax: `Util.muckException(#{ statements })`

Comment: It's not the answer I was hoping for, but I have to give the tick and +1 to you for completeness of answer.

Answer (score 5):

Could you just use `Callable<Void>`?

Comment: +1 - This is the simple solution.  The OP's implementation of the `call()` method needs to `return null;`, but that's a minor cosmetic issue / minor inconvenience.

Comment: Nice try - see edits in question. I must admit, if *you* (Jon) can't think of an answer, there probably isn't such an interface.

Comment: @Bohemian: but why restrict your "catch-never-happening-exceptions" API to `void` methods/code blocks? Couldn't I want to run some code that returns a value *and* might throw an exception?

Comment: @JS For that I can use Callable<T>, which I am already doing.

Comment: @Bohemian: So your *only* reason for searching for another interface is that you want to avoid having to write `return null;` each time? Then introduce this: `abstract class VoidCallable implements Callable<Void> { public Void call() { voidCall(); return null; } public abstract void voidCall(); }`.

Comment: @Joachim Yes. If I introduce my own class, implementing Callable<Void> adds nothing - I might as well just write what I want.

Comment: @Bohemian: not exactly: it "adds" simplicity by not requiring a second set of "execute this and swallow exceptions" methods (you use the same ones you use with other `Callable` objects) *and* it helps avoid writing the useless `return null;` each time.

Comment: OK I see what you mean. Perhaps I can at least use the same util method. Thanks for the thoughts.

Comment: BTW, this answer, although well voted up, does **not** answer the question, because Callable<Void> does not have a method signature of `void call() throws Exception` - it is `Void call() throws Exception`, which is quite different.

Comment: @Bohemian: It's different, but it conveys the same intent - i.e. a method which might throw any exception but doesn't return a meaningful value. Personally I'd rather use this and take the very slight elegance hit of a `return null;` instead of using `AutoClosable`, but it's your call..

Comment: @Jon Agreed - `AutoClosable.close()` is far uglier than `return null;` Essentially, it seems there isn't a "correct" answer. (@irreputable's answer provided discussion and another approach)

Answer (score 0):

Just use Callable, ignore the return value and document things as ignoring the returned value and recommend returning null.  Just because you *can* return something does not mean you *have* to.

Comment: Yeah you do have to at least return null from call(), and it's just ugly. I'm looking for something simple and neat. See edited question

Answer (score 0):

I would just use `Callable<Void>` and learn to love it. ;)

You can have the checked exception not declared with the following.

```
Runnable runs = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            // do something
        } catch(Exception e) {
            // rethrows anything without the compiler knowing.
            // the method is deprecated but can be used on the current thread.
            Thread.currentThread().stop(e);
        }
    }
});

Future future = executorService.submit(run);
try {
   future.get();
} catch (ExecutionException ee) {
    Throwable e = ee.getCause(); // can be the checked exception above.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> and not have to code loads of perfunctory try/catch blocks that will never be exercised.

I had the same issue and fixed it a little differently

```
// Exceptions class
public RuntimeException wrap(Exception e) {
   return e instanceof RuntimeException ? ((RuntimeException)e) : new RuntimeException(e);
}

// user code
try {
  foo.bar();
} catch (Exception e) {
 throw Exceptions.wrap(e);
}
```

Comment: One should never `catch Exception`, unless you *really* have to (due to library API etc). Unless you're catching `Exception` (or similar), you won't ever get a RuntimeException, the the wrap will never be passes a runtime. That means your suggestion is equivalent to: `catch SomeException (e) { throw new RuntimeException(e);}`. But thanks for answering.

Comment: I'm not sure what you said there, but I am sure this works. Tried and tested.

Comment: I'm not saying "it doesn't work". I'm saying "it isn't a good idea": `catch Exception` is not a good pattern.